# Feeding, nutrition, diet, eating and food tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently we have a 
[feeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeding), [nutrition](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition), [diet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet), [eating](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eating) and [food](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) tag.

Which of these should we keep and/or synonymize, Suggestions?

Comment: I can't edit your post for some reason, but if you spell it as `[tag:nutrition]`, it'll link to the actual tag. In this case, it would make it a lot easier to look up whether they all cover questions that should be grouped under one tag.

Answer (score 9):

I think these are two different groups: nutrition/diet/food, and feeding/eating.  The first is about the food itself; the second is about the act of eating.  We seem to have some need for both, so those are the synonym groups I'd make.

Comment: I think those would be sensible groupings. We'd have to ensure that the tag wiki excerpts will reflect the difference between them though, maybe along the lines of `diet = what to eat`, `feeding = when/how to feed`. We'll also have to retag accordingly.

Comment: I'm a big fan of tag cross-refernces in tag wikis.  ("This tag is about X.  See also tags Y and Z.")

Answer (score 1):

As I've asked the same question without recognizing this one, I put [my thoughts](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/263/58) here, too (and add some more things).

> Both [diet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) and [nutrition](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) are synonyms, I would prefer nutrition as the main tag as it sounds more professional and doesn't carry the connotation of weight-loss.
>
> [feeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeding) should be perceived as the actual process of feeding (and methods used during the process). Which would have to be noted in the tags wiki excerpt.

The tag excerpt of [feeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeding) already describes the desired use of the tag, I currently disagree to make [eating](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eating) a synonym. Eating actually refers to the process of the animal eating stuff and feeding refers to the owner offering the pet some food, if the tag wiki excerpt of eating is edited it could make the distinction clear.

[diet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) and [food](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) should be made synonyms of [nutrition](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition), the tag wiki excerpt of nutrition currently states: *"Refers to the question regarding nutritional aspects of diet."*; diet reads: *"Refers to the question concerning about food diet of their pets."*; and foods excerpt is emtpy.

Comment: I would make diet the main tag and nutrition the synonym.  Nutrition is one aspect of diet, but wouldn't cover, e.g., questions about dry vs wet food, or transitioning from one type of food to another, or hypo-allergenic diets.

Comment: Feeding / Eating / Drinking is discussed on [this answer](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/a/294/58), too.