# Synonyms diet, nutrition and usage of feeding

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We have several questions tagged [diet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) or [nutrition](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition). I really don't see any difference between them.

[feeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeding) sound similarly close, too.

Answer (score 1):

Both [diet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) and [nutrition](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) are synonyms, I would prefer nutrition as the main tag as it sounds more professional and doesn't carry the connotation of weight-loss.

[feeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeding) should be perceived as the actual process of feeding (and methods used during the process). Which would have to be noted in the tags wiki excerpt.

Comment: This sounds like a great way to do it.